# How to update longblob image field in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit']) and isset($_GET['slider_id']))
    {
        $date=date('Y-m-j');
        $imgName=$_FILES['image']['name'];
        $cont=file_get_contents($imgName);
         $cont=addslashes($cont);

         if($imgName=="")
         {
        //$imgData =addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['name']));
        $res=mysqli_query($connect,'UPDATE `slider_images` SET `image`=\''.$cont.'\' WHERE id=\''.$_GET['slider_id'].'\'');
             if($res)
             {
                 echo "Updated";
             }
             else
             {
                 echo "Not Updated";
             }
        }
     }
```

Not understanding the real issue behind this and i have refereed many solution's but no success in that.All solution's i found they tell to store images in folder and store the file name in database table.Reason behind storing images in database is, only 4 images are to be stored, so why not to store them in database. Please guide me through this issue. Following is the issue i am talking about.
[Warning Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8Its.png)
Thank's in advance.

Comment: Do this, `$cont=file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);`

Comment: @Rajdeep Paul : Thank's sir it worked...

Comment: Glad I could help. I've also included an explanation in my answer below. Please mark the answer as *accepted* if it resolved your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$_FILES['file']['name']` is the original name of the uploaded file from the user's computer.
- `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` will contain the temporary file name of the file on the server. This is just a temporary placeholder until you process the file.

So you should access the file like this:

```
$cont=file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
```

---

**Sidenote:** Instead of `if($res){ ... }` use `mysqli_affected_rows()` to get number of rows affected by this `UPDATE` query, like this:

```
mysqli_query($connect,"UPDATE `slider_images` SET `image`='".$cont."' WHERE id='".$_GET['slider_id']."'");
if(mysqli_affected_rows($connect)){
    echo "Updated";
}else{
    echo "Not Updated";
}
```

Here's the reference:

- [`mysqli_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)